# How to disable virtual keyboard when in landscape mode?

Tags: keyboard, orientation

I have a Droid 2 (on Gingerbread); The device has a physical keyboard.

I use virtual keyboard in portrait mode *sometimes*, but never in landscape mode (since I have physical keyboard.)

Is there a way that would allow me to disable virtual keyboard when in landscape mode, but leave it available for portrait mode?

Comment: Doesn't the soft keyboard go away if you open the keyboard tray? It did on my Droid, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but not an easy way. You can use keyboards like [Null keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.wparam.nullkeyboard).

> A keyboard that does nothing.
>   Yes, really.
>   This keyboard is useful if you have an external bluetooth keyboard paired with your phone and you want to stop the on-screen keyboard from popping up all the time.

The problem is every time you change mode you have to change the input method.

Comment: You might be able to automatically change the OSK using an automation app. I use Llama(https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) or you might want to use its more well-known app, Tasker.

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch the screen. Instead, use the tab and the arrow keys on the bluetooth keyboard to navigate. This way, the pop-up keyboard will never come up.

It is a challenge. There are a lot of shortcuts and tricks to learn, but it's more convenient once you get the hang of it. I guess the simplest answer would be to get a bluetooth mouse as well. Use that to select things instead of touching the screen.