# How do I disable the on screen keyboard? I have a USB keyboard attached

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, keyboard

I have a ZeniThink C91 using Ice Cream.  I also have a case that has a USB keyboard.  How do i disable the android Keyboard so only the USB keyboard is active?  Ice Cream 4.0

Comment: I was sure we had a question like this already but I can't find it.  IIRC, the solution was to install a software keyboard that was either a dummy and never showed on-screen or that was smart enough not to show when the USB keyboard was being used.

Comment: Actually I found the task and killed, now I can see the whole screen when typing on my USB keyboard.  But thanks.

Comment: @Matthew were you thinking of [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16652/how-to-disable-virtual-keyboard-when-in-landscape-mode) ?

Comment: @jlehenbauer I think so, good find!

Answer (score 5):

[Null Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wparam.nullkeyboard) is what you want. I do this same thing with my bluetooth keyboard. It does require you manually switch the input method each time, but keeps the pesky on-screen keyboard from popping up.

Another option I've used is to use [the method described here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23847/changing-layout-of-physical-keyboard/23953#23953) to program one of your keys to a <kbd>Back</kbd> button, which you can press to remove the on-screen keyboard each time it pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search for an alternative to the stock-keyboard delivered with your android device.
There are keyboards that have hardware keyboard detection and settings to explicitly turn off the on-screen keyboard, [blueduino soft keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.weebmeister.blueduino.demo) for example.