# Changing   layout of hardware keyboard

Tags: keyboard, sony-xperia-mini-pro

How I can change a layout or add a new layout to physical keyboard of  Xperia mini pro phone?

I want for example remap <kbd>?</kbd> to ''ə'' and <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> to ''Ə'', or <kbd>س</kbd> to <kbd>ی</kbd> in Persian layout or even add new layout (Persian 2 layout).

You can find build-in layout [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/wp/2012/02/08/localise-custom-roms-for-different-xperia-pro-and-xperia-mini-pro-keyboards/), actually I want to add a new layout to them.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean by "layout"? Are you wanting to re-bind keys?

Comment: @Reza, are you rooted?

Comment: @jlehenbauer Yes, my device is rooted

Comment: @Reza Perfect! i'm actually doing this right now to my phone. i'll type it up for you!

Comment: Any purpose of photo?

Comment: @SachinShekhar It's for showing what is a physical keyboard, for those that never see one! ;)

Answer (score 9):

First, obtain the following:

- Android device with **root** access
- **adb** on your computer

  - *you can do without this, but that just means a lot of time copying files back and forth to your phone and moving them with something like [Root Explorer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.speedsoftware.rootexplorer%26hl%3Den&ei=82zRT__iOY2o8QTz27TTAw&usg=AFQjCNGaFfPNg78m7bL8dpNx8HMrZoHBGA&sig2=lYo_vUNiYEyDD0MXcrdflw)*
- text editor

Now,

1. Plug your phone in to your computer and navigate to the `/system/usr/keylayout/` folder, using **adb** or a Terminal Emulator
2. Pull the file for your keylayout. Mine was called `qwerty.kl` and looked like this:

> ```
> key 399   GRAVE
> key 2     1
> key 3     2
> key 4     3
> key 5     4
> key 6     5
> key 7     6
> key 8     7
> key 9     8
> key 10    9
> key 11    0
> key 158   BACK              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 230   SOFT_RIGHT        WAKE
> key 60    SOFT_RIGHT        WAKE
> key 107   ENDCALL           WAKE_DROPPED
> key 62    ENDCALL           WAKE_DROPPED
> key 229   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 139   MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 59    MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 127   SEARCH            WAKE_DROPPED
> key 217   SEARCH            WAKE_DROPPED
> key 228   POUND
> key 227   STAR
> key 231   CALL              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 61    CALL              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 232   DPAD_CENTER       WAKE_DROPPED
> key 108   DPAD_DOWN         WAKE_DROPPED
> key 103   DPAD_UP           WAKE_DROPPED
> key 102   HOME              WAKE
> key 105   DPAD_LEFT         WAKE_DROPPED
> key 106   DPAD_RIGHT        WAKE_DROPPED
> key 115   VOLUME_UP         WAKE
> key 114   VOLUME_DOWN       WAKE
> key 116   POWER             WAKE
> key 212   CAMERA
>
> key 16    Q
> key 17    W
> key 18    E
> key 19    R
> key 20    T
> key 21    Y
> key 22    U
> key 23    I
> key 24    O
> key 25    P
> key 26    LEFT_BRACKET
> key 27    RIGHT_BRACKET
> key 43    BACKSLASH
>
> key 30    A
> key 31    S
> key 32    D
> key 33    F
> key 34    G
> key 35    H
> key 36    J
> key 37    K
> key 38    L
> key 39    SEMICOLON
> key 40    APOSTROPHE
> key 14    DEL
>
> key 44    Z
> key 45    X
> key 46    C
> key 47    V
> key 48    B
> key 49    N
> key 50    M
> key 51    COMMA
> key 52    PERIOD
> key 53    SLASH
> key 28    ENTER
>
> key 56    ALT_LEFT
> key 100   ALT_RIGHT
> key 42    SHIFT_LEFT
> key 54    SHIFT_RIGHT
> key 15    TAB
> key 57    SPACE
> key 150   EXPLORER
> key 155   ENVELOPE        
>
> key 12    MINUS
> key 13    EQUALS
> key 215   AT
>
> # On an AT keyboard: ESC, F10
> key 1     BACK              WAKE_DROPPED
> key 68    MENU              WAKE_DROPPED
> ```

3. Now, play with the file!

To change `L` to `M`, `key 38    L`->`key 38   M`

Obviously, `key ###` maps to certain keys. **This can be tedious, as you mostly have to guess and check the key numbers.**

Here is what I've found so far for mine, hopefully it helps:

[image: keyboard layout]

The next part is the mapping. Simply put the character or command, such as `HOME` after the key number.

The last part (`WAKE/WAKE_DROPPED`) determines if the key wakes the screen. `WAKE`=wake the screen `WAKE_DROPPED`=don't wake screen.

Now get it like you want it, and enjoy!

This will work with English-based keyboards, after that it's a little more guess and check, because you will need to know the foreign character that corresponds to the English character that corresponds to the key #.

Comment: An easy solution for figuring out key mapping is CWM recovery's key test option. You press a key, it prints the number.

Comment: @Thanks, It seems that these files just can be used to map physical keys to some predefined names, How I can map shift+space to "@" sign, or "?" to 'ə' letter? Where layout files for various languages are placed? How we can add a new languages to language list?

Answer (score 0):

On a CM9.1 based device we found the following:

- System Settings

Section Device

- Advanced

There is only the one option: Keyboard layout

This affects the hardware keyboard layout.

However not sure if this works for stock roms.