# How can I automatically disable the onscreen keyboard when a Bluetooth keyboard is connected?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the on screen keyboard? I have a USB keyboard attached](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/how-do-i-disable-the-on-screen-keyboard-i-have-a-usb-keyboard-attached)

I'm using a 9.7" Bauhn Android tablet from Aldi running Ice CreamSandwich. I have a Kensington universal keyboard (and case) made for 10“ tablets including Android that I use with my tablet. Is there a way to automatically disable the onscreen keyboard when my Bluetooth one is connected?

Answer (score 1):

Not automatic (per se), but you can use something like [Null Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wparam.nullkeyboard&hl=en) which is a null input method you can enable when you have your Bluetooth keyboard connected so the soft keyboard quits from popping up.

Also, in my experience, Cyanogenmod9 ICS ROMs prevents the keyboard from appearing when an external one is connected. It might be worth seeing if they have a distribution for your device.